# Getting strange result using get-adgroupmember for groups that have only one member

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a script that reads a list of groups from a table in SQL Server and populates another table with the group members.  This is used as part of a SQL Security audit.  The script works fine with one exception.  If the group only has one member, the data is incorrect.
SamAccountName should be X012345 and name should be Jane Doe, but instead I'm getting "D" and "".

Here's part of the code:

```
foreach ($groupID in $dbdata)
{
$Scan_Date = $dbdata.Scan_Date[$dn]
$group = $dbdata.groupID[$dn]
$Group_Name = $dbdata.Group_Name[$dn]
[array]$groupusers = get-adgroupmember $Group_Name -Recursive | select SamAccountName, name
#$groupusers
$gn = 0
[string]$col1 = ""
[string]$col2 = ""
    foreach ($name in $groupusers)
    {
    $groupusers[$gn]
    $col1 = $groupusers.SamAccountName[$gn]
    $col2 = $groupusers.name[$gn]
    $col2 = $col2.replace("'","`'`'")
 write-host $Group_Name, $col1, $col2
$query = @"
INSERT INTO $ssi_table
           ([GroupID]
           ,[Scan_Date]
           ,[Group_Name]
           ,[User_ID]
           ,[User_Name])
     VALUES ('$Group_Name', '$Scan_Date', '$Group_Name', '$col2', '$col3')
"@
Run-SqlQuery -Query $query -Database $ssi_database -Server $ssi_instance

    $gn = $gn + 1
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about change:

```
$col1 = $groupusers.SamAccountName[$gn]
$col2 = $groupusers.name[$gn]
```

to:

```
$col1 = $groupusers[$gn].SamAccountName
$col2 = $groupusers[$gn].name
```

For single value, you are getting the "$gn"th character from the SamAccountName/name.

One more thing, where does $col3 come from? 
You assign value to $col1 and $col2 but insert $col2 and $col3 to DB.
Is this a typo?